# Query data from Parse in a ListView position

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I have a small problem in my project. I was querying data in parse to `ListView`, and I want when user longclick in the item, it will show the item's detail. But  when I use the code it gives `NullPointerException`. Here is my code :

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object object = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            final Trade trade = (Trade)object;
            String idTrade = trade.getId();
            final Trade[] mTrade = new Trade[1];
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("trade");
            query.whereEqualTo("trade_id",idTrade);
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (parseObject == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        mTrade[0] = (Trade) parseObject;
                    }
                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Topic "+mTrade[0].getTopic()+
                    "\nAddress "+mTrade[0].getAddress()+"\nGiá "+mTrade[0].getCost(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//NullPonterException
```

logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.evan.findingbus.Trade.getTopic()' on a null object reference
```

Tell me How to fix it? please!

Comment: stack trace for null pointer exception please

Comment: i edited , can you help me

Comment: mTrade[0].getTopic() this value is nulll. can you check in data browser in parse if it exists ?

Comment: no if i call Toast.make..... inside public void done()... it will be work.. i don't understand why?

Comment: reason is getFirstInBackground is asynchronous call as a result it goes in different thread for parse and your toast.makeText which is outside runs before result comes as a result object is null. Simple !

Comment: use getFirst() rather than getFirstInBackground to make it synchronous

Comment: can you help me fix the code :( i'm a beginer :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reason is getFirstInBackground is asynchronous call as a result it goes in different thread for parse and your toast.makeText which is outside runs before result comes as a result object is null. Simple !

You can code as follows:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object object = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            final Trade trade = (Trade)object;
            String idTrade = trade.getId();
            final Trade[] mTrade = new Trade[1];
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("trade");
            query.whereEqualTo("trade_id",idTrade);
            ParseObject result = query.getFirst();
            mTrade[0] = (Trade) result;


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Topic "+mTrade[0].getTopic()+
                    "\nAddress "+mTrade[0].getAddress()+"\nGiá "+mTrade[0].getCost(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//NullPonterException

        }
```